# Rails - Replace Text with Image in link_to 'Delete'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, ruby-on-rails-4, action

The basic snippet of code I am trying to alter is:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

My question is: can the text 'Delete' be replaced to display an image which would perform the same action as to original code? i.e. replace 'Delete' with an image of an 'X'

I have tried:

```
<%= link_to 'img src="path_to_image"', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Wasn't really expecting the code above to work, but I thought I would give it a shot. As expected it returned "a href="path_to_image"" in place of 'Delete'

Also thought I should add

```
rails -v
Rails 4.1.0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) helper:

```
<%= link_to post, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} do %>
  <%= image_tag(your_image_url) %>
<% end %>
```

or, if you want to do it in one line:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(your_image_url), post, method: :delete, {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

About your issue with path, since your image file seems to be placed in proper assets directory, this should work:

```
<%= link_to post, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} do %>
  <%= image_tag('x_small_icon') %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Or he can do it in one line if he prefers `<%= link_to image_tag(image_url), post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`

Comment: @RichPeck what difference does my first name make? :)

Comment: Nothing - you just keep posting epic answers, so I upvote automatically!

Comment: @RichPeck thanks for appreciation. Unfortunately not all of my answers are good, but I try to make them so. :)

Comment: It's the cult of Marek!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm still learning and am still having a few issues. I tried:

    `<%= link_to image_tag('/app/assets/images/x_small_icon'), post, method: :delete, {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>`

where do I store the icon and how do I specifically call it?

Comment: @MaxWilliams apparently. And I don't know what to think about it. :)

Comment: @RichPeck Me too inspire with his answers.

Comment: @jzg.dev I edited my answer to reflect your problem with path.

Comment: awesome! thanks a lot... I couldn't get it to work at first but its working after adding file extension to the path name

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

```
<%= link_to image_tag('/img/img.png'), post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nobody's actually pointed out quite why your original attempt doesn't work:

```
<%= link_to 'img src="path_to_image"', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

The reason is that the first argument to link_to is not a valid `img` tag - it's missing the `<` and `>`.  Remember that the first argument is just including into the content of the resulting `a` tag as is, with no modifications.  If you changed it to

```
<%= link_to '<img src="path_to_image">', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

then it would work.  It's better to do what the other posters have suggested, which is to use a rails image_tag helper, but i thought someone should point out why your original code was broken rather than just tell you how to do it :)

Comment: You're right, my answer lacks this explanation. +1 from me.